# Custom local menu in GNOME 2

Tags: gnome2

```
[USER@LAPTOP ~] dpkg -l | grep -i gnome-desktop
ii  gnome-desktop-data                                          1:2.30.2-0ubuntu1                               Common files for GNOME desktop apps
ii  libgnome-desktop-2-17                                       1:2.30.2-0ubuntu1                               Utility library for loading .desktop files - r
[USER@LAPTOP ~] lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
[USER@LAPTOP ~]
```

How can I create new entries here?:

[image]

So that we can add for example: not just new "empty file" - rather "new openoffice odt", or GIMP image, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it with a nautilus script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SABLONFILE="/home/USER/TEMPLATES/PNG.png"
UJFILENAME="./newPNG.png"

which zenity > /dev/null 2>&1; if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then exit 1; fi
if [ -s "$UJFILENAME" ]; then zenity --error --text="FILENAME ALREADY EXISTS"; exit 1; fi;
cp "$SABLONFILE" "$UJFILENAME"
if ! [ -s "$UJFILENAME" ]; then zenity --error --text="$UJFILENAME wasn't created? wtf?"; exit 1; fi;
```

so the script will copy a template file from TEMPLATES